Next.js: Passing Props through component with a <form>
I am learning Nextjs and i need to pass a variable through a form component, and then further through its server action component. (i think this is called prop drilling and i dont know if theres a more elegant way to do it..) It is needed for the database query. i am working loosly on a tutorial.
Please excuse super naive mistakes since i am a beginner. So im sure there are other mistakes in it, but i am focusing on accessing this fetchuserid value for my db entry:
So here is my page.tsx:
i need to pass fetchuserid through AddBalanceForm
import { fetchUser } from "@/app/components/fetchdata";
import type { UsersDb } from "@/app/components/definitions";
import ThisUserTable from "@/app/components/thisusertable";
import AddBalanceForm from "@/app/components/addbalanceform";

export default async function Page({ params: { slug } }) {


    const fetchuserid = Number(slug); 
    const user: UsersDb = await fetchUser(fetchuserid); 


    return (

      <main>
      <ThisUserTable user={user} />
      
      <AddBalanceForm fetchuserid={fetchuserid}/>

      </main>
    );
        
}

addbalanceform.tsx
'use client';


import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
import { userAddBalance } from "./adddata";
import SubmitButton  from "./submit-button";
import { EMPTY_FORM_STATE } from "./utils";
import { FieldError } from "./utils";
import { useToastMessage } from "./use-toast-message";
import { useFormReset } from "./useformreset";


export default function AddBalanceForm ({ fetchuserid }: { fetchuserid: number })  {

  const [formState, action] = useFormState(
    userAddBalance, 
    EMPTY_FORM_STATE,
    
  );

  const noScriptFallback = useToastMessage(formState);
  const formRef = useFormReset(formState);

  return (

    <form action={action} className="flex flex-col gap-y-2" ref={formRef}>


      <label htmlFor="amount">amount</label>
      <textarea id="amount" name="amount" className="border-2" />
      <span className="text-xs text-red-400">
      <FieldError formState={formState} name="text" />
      </span>


      <SubmitButton label="Create" loading="Creating ..." />
      <span className="font-bold">{formState.message}</span>

      {noScriptFallback}
    </form>
  );
};

the server action is this:
'use server';

import { z } from 'zod';
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache';
import BetterSqlite3 from 'better-sqlite3';
import { FormState, toFormState } from './utils';



let db : BetterSqlite3.Database;
db = new BetterSqlite3("./coffeev1.db");

const addBalanceSchema = z.object({
  amount: z
          .coerce
          .number()
          .min(1)
          .max(1000),
});

  export async function userAddBalance(
    formState: FormState,
    formData: FormData,
    fetchuserid: number,
    ) {
    // Insert data into the database
    try {
      const { amount } = addBalanceSchema.parse({
        amount: formData.get('amount')
  
      });
      const amountInCents = amount * 100;
      
      const writeuser = db.prepare(
        `
        UPDATE user_registry
        SET kaffeestand = ${amountInCents}
        WHERE id = ?1
      `);

      writeuser.run( { 1: fetchuserid}); 

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Database Error:', error);



    }
   

    // Revalidate the cache for the page and redirect the user.
    revalidatePath(`/users/${fetchuserid}`);

    return toFormState('SUCCESS', 'Message created');
  }
  

now i dont know how to pass the prop to the server action. i think it needs to go in this block:
export default function AddBalanceForm ({ fetchuserid }: { fetchuserid: number })  {

  const [formState, action] = useFormState(
    userAddBalance, 
    EMPTY_FORM_STATE,
    
  );
....

thank you for your help.
greetings

In the AddBalanceForm component, include fetchuserid as a hidden input field so that it is submitted with the form data:
1. Modifying the Form Component
AddBalanceForm.tsx


'use client';

import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
import { userAddBalance } from "./adddata";
import SubmitButton from "./submit-button";
import { EMPTY_FORM_STATE } from "./utils";
import { FieldError } from "./utils";
import { useToastMessage } from "./use-toast-message";
import { useFormReset } from "./useformreset";

interface AddBalanceFormProps {
  fetchuserid: number;
}

export default function AddBalanceForm({ fetchuserid }: AddBalanceFormProps) {
  const [formState, action] = useFormState(
    (formState: FormState, formData: FormData) => userAddBalance(formState, formData, fetchuserid), // Pass fetchuserid to the action
    EMPTY_FORM_STATE
  );

  const noScriptFallback = useToastMessage(formState);
  const formRef = useFormReset(formState);

  return (
    <form action={action} className="flex flex-col gap-y-2" ref={formRef}>
      <input type="hidden" name="fetchuserid" value={fetchuserid} /> {/* Hidden input field */}

      <label htmlFor="amount">Amount</label>
      <textarea id="amount" name="amount" className="border-2" />
      <span className="text-xs text-red-400">
        <FieldError formState={formState} name="amount" />
      </span>

      <SubmitButton label="Create" loading="Creating ..." />
      <span className="font-bold">{formState.message}</span>

      {noScriptFallback}
    </form>
  );
}



2. Modifying the Server Action
Update the userAddBalance function to extract fetchuserid from the formData if you are passing it through a hidden field:
adddata.ts


'use server';

import { z } from 'zod';
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache';
import BetterSqlite3 from 'better-sqlite3';
import { FormState, toFormState } from './utils';

let db: BetterSqlite3.Database;
db = new BetterSqlite3("./coffeev1.db");

const addBalanceSchema = z.object({
  amount: z.coerce.number().min(1).max(1000),
});

export async function userAddBalance(
  formState: FormState,
  formData: FormData
) {
  // Extract fetchuserid from formData
  const fetchuserid = Number(formData.get('fetchuserid'));

  try {
    const { amount } = addBalanceSchema.parse({
      amount: formData.get('amount')
    });
    const amountInCents = amount * 100;

    const writeuser = db.prepare(`
      UPDATE user_registry
      SET kaffeestand = ?
      WHERE id = ?
    `);

    writeuser.run(amountInCents, fetchuserid);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Database Error:', error);
  }

  // Revalidate the cache for the page and redirect the user.
  revalidatePath(`/users/${fetchuserid}`);

  return toFormState('SUCCESS', 'Message created');
}




it worked!! thank you so much <3
